# Compact way to map an IEnumerable to an ILookup with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

A situation I've found myself in a few times: I have an `IEnumerable<T>`, and a function `map` that maps an instance of `T` to an `IEnumerable<U>`.  I want to produce an `ILookup<T, U>` defined by that map.

This seems like a pretty common use case, but I haven't found a compact way to produce the lookup.  In particular, `enumT.ToLookup( t=>t, t=>map(t))` produces an `ILookup<T, IEnumerable<U>>`.

Comment: I don't really follow.  You have, say an array of `t[]` and a function that maps an individual `t` to an `IEnumerable<U>` and you want to somehow use that function to produce a singular `U` for each `T`?

Comment: @stephen.vakil Not quite.  He wants to have an `IEnumerable<U>` for each `T`, but what he has at the moment is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<U>>` for each `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `SelectMany` to flatten the sequence out before calling `ToLookup`.

```
var lookup = sequence.SelectMany(key => Foo(key), (key, value) => new { key, value, })
    .ToLookup(pair => pair.key, pair => pair.value);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that overload of `SelectMany`, and it's much nicer than what I'd previously been doing.